# d3 appears to silently truncate array in .data() method

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js

Working through some D3 examples, I believe have found a d3 bug or behavior I can’t explain .

D3 appears to truncate Arrays when calling a .data() method .

```
<script>

    d3.csv('medium_january.csv', function(error, data) {
      if (error) {
          console.error('Error getting or parsing the data.');
          throw error;
      }
      var chart = bubbleChart().width(600).height(400);
      d3.select('#chart').data(data).call(chart);
      //here data has 43 elements with the 1st beginning "how flex...
    });

</script>
```

In bubble chart.js

```
function bubbleChart() {
    var width = 960,
        height = 960,
        maxRadius = 6,
        columnForColors = "category",
        columnForRadius = "views";

    function chart(selection) {
        var data = selection.enter().data();
//here data has 42 elements with the first being "How I went from zero


        var div = selection,
            svg = div.selectAll('svg');
        svg.attr('width', width).attr('height', height);
        //rest of script
```

Working example here

https://bl.ocks.org/dmesquita/37d8efdb3d854db8469af4679b8f984a

The problem appears in bubblechart.js

If the number of entries in data in the first block is 43, it becomes 42 in chart() function. The length of selection.enter() is 43 but after .data() we only have 42 entries .

I have tried using different data sets thinking that a bad data may be forcing .data() to fail but got the same results with other data. If if there were bad data i would expect an error and not silently skip.

Why is .data() silently truncating what appears to be the first  array value ?

Comment: I edited the example to show where the array is being truncated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's happening here is that since you use `.select('#chart').data(data)` the first item in your array is being data-bound to your `div`.  `.enter()` is then just returning the rest of the array.  This is a strange way to use data-binding.  Essentially, all you are after is a way to pass your data into your function.  This could be accomplished much more conventionally as:

```
d3.select('#chart').call(chart, data);
```

Where your function definition becomes:

```
function chart(selection, data) {
    var div = selection,
        svg = div.selectAll('svg');
    svg.attr('width', width).attr('height', height);

    ...
```

Update [block](http://blockbuilder.org/anonymous/b2c069e550faceed234fd2f707b423f0).

**Response to Comment**

Apologies if I was unclear.  You have an element with an `id` of chart on the page.  You then bind your data to it.  Since the element exists the first item in your array is bound to it.  You then `.enter()` the selection, this returns the rest of the array, representing items which **do not** have existing elements.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Thanks for clearer function but it does not explain why we loose a data element .  The first csv entry disappears  The first array item should be "Flexbox..." and its not .

Comment: I understand what you are saying but it not clear why data is loosing an array elements. elements which are not divs but data . if you look at the example link i posted, throw breakpoints at points where I commented in my code sample. Compare data between the break points . The first array element is different and the array is one shorter.

Comment: @stimpy, I understand what you are saying.  Your element isn't lost at all.  `d3` data-binding is all about binding data to `dom` elements.  Your initial `.data` call binds your data to your `div`.  The `div` exists the the first array element is bound to it.  `.enter()` then returns the data items **that haven't been bound** yet.  Try `selection.data()`, this is the `update` selection (those items that already exist), it'll return an array of 1; your first item.

Comment: this doesn't explain why the csv data we started with is loosing an element in the original  code sample . In that no binding has taken place , we don't bind to the svg until the line after, where we data array has already lost its first element.

Comment: @stimpy Mark's answer does explain why you have one element less **in the enter selection**. The data array, however, remains unchanged.

Answer (score 2):

I'm writing this second answer just to show you that [Mark's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44477750/5768908) is indeed correct and explains what's happening here (I'm not a big fan of *argument from authority*, but if you click at the [D3 top users](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/d3.js/topusers) you're gonna see that Mark is among the all time top answerers... of course nobody is perfect, but it's always a good idea taking the opinion of a top answerer seriously and studying carefully what he/she is saying).

#### The size of an enter selection

Clearly, your data array has 43 elements. That doesn't change, unless you use a method that modifies that array.

But the issue here is that you're measuring the size of the "enter" selection, not the size of the data array. And `data()` definitely **does not** change the size of the data array.

That being said, let's see what is an "enter" selection. This image provide a good explanation:

[image]

In a nutshell, the "enter" selection contains all data elements that don't correspond to a DOM element.

In your code, however, the "enter" selection doesn't have the same size of the data array, because, as Mark said, you are binding data to an already existing DOM element. We can show this modifying your code...

```
d3.select('#chart').data(data).call(chart);
```

... to this, which is the same:

```
var sel = d3.select('#chart').data(data);
chart(sel);
```

Now, using `sel`, we can compare the size of the data array with the size of the enter selection, **before** you call `chart:

```
console.log("the data array has " + data.length + " elements");
console.log("the enter selection has " + sel.enter().size() + " elements");
```

And this will be the result:

```
the data array has 43 elements
the enter selection has 42 elements
```

Here is the modified bl.ocks, have a look at the console: https://bl.ocks.org/anonymous/5204c7ee3e4e15a2b1bbfd7633b1deb6

If you still have any doubt that your first datum is bound to that div, just do...

```
console.log(d3.select("#chart").datum())
```

And you'll see this:

```
Object {
    title: "How Flexbox works — explained with big, colorful, animated gifs", 
    category: "Design", 
    views: "5700"}
```

#### Enter selection: a practical example

What confuses a lot of people regarding `data()` is that it defines the "enter" and "exit" selections based on the elements successfully bound to data.

That being said, people tend to think that, for creating divs, you have to `selectAll("div")`, or that for creating paragraphs you have to `selectAll("p")`, as in:

```
selection.selectAll("p")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("p")
    etc...
```

And that's not correct. Actually, if you `selectAll("p")` before the `data()` function, you run the risk of selecting any existing paragraph in that page, and your "enter" selection will be shorter than what it should be.

For instance, have a look at this example:

```js
var data = ["foo", "bar", "baz"];
var body = d3.select("body");

var newDivs = body.selectAll(null)
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("div")
  .html(function(d){ return d})
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<div>Hello</div>
```

As I'm using `selectAll(null)`, my "enter" selection has **all** the elements of my data array, regardless the fact that there is already a div in that page.

Now, have a look at this other example:

```js
var data = ["foo", "bar", "baz"];
var body = d3.select("body");

var newDivs = body.selectAll("div")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("div")
  .html(function(d){ return d})
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<div>Hello</div>
```

As you can see, due to the fact that there is already a div in that page, when I do `selectAll("div")` before the `data()` function, my first data element ("foo") is bound to that div, and my "enter" selection end up having only two divs.

Comment: @Gerado Thanks for the clarification . So the original code incorrectly graphs the enter selection rather then the data ?

Comment: @stimpy The code doesn't *incorrectly graphs the enter selection rather then the data*. As any D3 code, it append elements using the "enter" selection. The problem is the way you're defining that enter selection. Also, the data-binding in that code is not the idiomatic D3.

Comment: @Gerado is not my code but an example that had confusing usage/results. bubble chat.js graphs the var "data" . If i understand you correctly that data being graphed is not the actual cvs data but rather the "not dom bound" data passed to bubble chart.js from the select . Is that right ?

Comment: Yes, the `data` in that bubble_chart.js is not the data created by `d3.csv` function.